# How do I restrict Nativescript to compile for x86_64 only?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-cli

How do I restrict 'tns build ios' to compile for x86_64 only?

It currently attempts to build my app for both i386 and x86_64. (ARCHS and VALID_ARCHS).

This fails to link plugins that where compiled for x86_64 and arm64 only.

Answer (score 0):

As of [NativeScript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript) `v5.1.1` it supports 64 bit, so you can do things like target iOS `11.4` in your `App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig` file.  Ex:

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.4;
```